# Convergence of a strange series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> For which value of $p$ does this series converge (absolutely converge)?
> $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}.$$

**My attempt:**
If $p\leq 0$, the given series diverges. So we just need to consider the case $p>0$. Notice that

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^p}
\leq\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}\right|
\leq\frac{1}{(n-1)^p}.$$

- If $p>1$, then the given series absolutely converges.
- If $p\leq 1$, then the given series diverges.

Can anyone continue the case $0<p\leq 1$?

Comment: Do not start the summation at $n=1$

Comment: ok, i edited the problem

Comment: Definitely a tough nut to crack. I'd try using the leibniz test and splitting the sequence into even and odd terms. Now you'd get two monotonous sequences converging to zero and you can maybe use limit theorems. This obviously just gives you a statement about convergence, not divergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct approach. One has
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p} = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\left(1+ \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n} \right)^{-p}= \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\left(1 - \dfrac{(-1)^np}{n} + O\left(\dfrac{1}{n^2} \right) \right)$$

i.e.
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p} = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^p}- \dfrac{p}{n^{p+1}} + O\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{2+p}} \right)$$

When $p>0$, the first term is the general term of a convergent alternating series ; and the second and the third term are general terms of absolutely convergent series.

Hence, for $p>0$, the series $\displaystyle \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}$ converges.